# Login through php with MySQL user - why not?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

In 2007 I made an internal site at my company, which is used to this day. At that time I didn't read too much about security and, since I had full control of the DB, I wrote user management system, which creates MySQL database user (yes, the 'whoever'@'specifichost' type). An admin would be needed to create such users, no user-sign-up was possible. Special script calculated what DB object rights were necessary. No "remember me" was possible.

Since now I need to revisit login/sign-up systems, and everyone asks about Facebook-type logins, I was wondering whether is it a bad idea to use MySQL user/password, granting their rights directly on the DB? (Assuming web hosting allows to create multiple users).

Comment: See also [webhost does not allow CREATE USER privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14076132)

Answer (score 2):

Typically, one would create users/permissions for the database based on a per-application or  per-service basis, not for individual application end user accounts.   MySQL's access controls are typically not granular enough to be used for user-specific privileges.   User-specific privileges would typically be implemented at the application layer, as oftentimes you need record-level control on who has access to what, something not allowed by MySQL.

This will also make things much easier for you in working with the database as far as connection management and troubleshooting issues, as all of your user-based access logic would reside only in your application layer.